# AWS Event Rule doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have following CFN event rule, which should kick off `MyLambda`. When i run this CFN template, I can see the rule is created with correct interval, correct input json and it is *ENABLED*. But it doesn't kick-off. I don't see any logs being created by my lambda (I am using a print statement).

But when i create similar rule using UI (same configuration etc), it works fine. I am not sure what i am missing here.

```
CWEventRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties:
        Description: "Description"
        Name: "CWEventRule"
        ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"
        State: "ENABLED"
        Targets:
          -
            Arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - "MyLambda"
                - "Arn"
            Id: "MyLambda"
            Input: "{\"jsonkey\":\"jsonvalue\"}"
```

---

Updated cfn template with role

```
CloudWatchEventRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
                -   Effect: "Allow"
                    Principal:
                        Service:
                            -   !Sub lambda.amazonaws.com
                            -   !Sub events.amazonaws.com
                    Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
        Path: "/"
        Policies:
            -   PolicyName: CloudWatchEventPolicy
                PolicyDocument:
                    Version: '2012-10-17'
                    Statement:
                        -   Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                -   "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                            Resource: "*"

CWEventRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties:
        Description: "Description"
        Name: "CWEventRule"
        ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"
        State: "ENABLED"
        RoleArn: !GetAtt [ CloudWatchEventRole, Arn ]
        Targets:
            -
                Arn:
                    Fn::GetAtt:
                        -   "MyLambda"
                        -   "Arn"
                Id: "MyLambda"
                Input: "{\"jsonkey\":\"jsonvalue\"}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give invoke Lambda permission to Event. This can be achieve by creating **AWS::Lambda::Permission** resource.

```
"PermissionInvokeLambdaRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
          "FunctionName": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyLambdaResouce", "Arn"] },
          "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
          "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
          "SourceArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyEventsRuleResource", "Arn"] }
    }
 },
```

Comment: thanks. is it different than the way i did it? I have updated my code in original post.

Comment: I don't think AWS::Events::Rule supports RoleArn as one of its properties. You may refer link here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html

Comment: Do you have cloudtrail on? check there for detailed event logging

Comment: Interesting. I was being confused by `RoleArn` property which is part of `Target` resource. Just added the permissions and it works. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

RoleArn should be associated with target as below. More information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html)

```
Targets:
    -
        Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
                -   "MyLambda"
                -   "Arn"
        Id: "MyLambda"
        Input: "{\"jsonkey\":\"jsonvalue\"}"
        RoleArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - CloudWatchEventRole
          - Arn
```